# Pandas, apply string join issue

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
letters = 'абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя '
done['text'] = done['text'].apply(lambda x : ''.join(s) for s in x if s in letters)
```

Is there any way to make it work? I need to remove all symbols from done['text] that not in letters

Comment: `done['text'] = done['text'].apply(lambda x : ''.join(s for s in x if s in letters))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`pandas.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) method for that. Here is an example:

```
letters = "fd"
series = pd.Series(["aaaafffaaaa", "bbbfdfdfdfbb", "fdfdfdf"])
# 0     aaaafffaaaa
# 1    bbbfdfdfdfbb
# 2         fdfdfdf
# dtype: object

series.str.replace('|'.join([ *letters ]), "")
# 0    aaaaaaaa
# 1       bbbbb
# 2
# dtype: object
```

The method expects a regular expression in the first argument, that's why I'm splitting the letters string and joining it back with '|' between them, to make an OR expression [ `'|'.join([ *letters ])` ].

In your case, you just need to swap `series` with `done["text"]`.